# Element goes missing during iteration of Arraylist

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

Can somebody explain to me whats wrong with the below piece of code ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
  l.add("1");
  l.add("2");
  l.add("3");
  l.add("4");

  for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
   if(l.get(i).equals("1"))
    l.remove(l.get(i));
   else
    System.out.println(l.get(i));
  }
 }
```

gives me an output of [3.4] instead of [2,3,4] .. Wheres my [2] ? I am a lil confused with this behavior of the List.. Great if somebody could explain..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are you using `l.remove(l.get(i))` if you can just use `l.remove(i)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is:
When i = 0 you remove the first element and i becomes 1
When i = 1 you are now at the third element, because you have shifted everything down by 1 so you write "3"
When i = 2 you write the third element which is "4"

Giving you an output of "3","4"

An alternate implementation might be:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Item {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("1");
        l.add("2");
        l.add("3");
        l.add("4");

        Iterator<String> iter = l.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            String value = iter.next();
            if("1".equals(value))
            {
                iter.remove();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should definitely use Iterator to remove elements whenever possible, to avoid having to manually decrement the index variable. It's a lot safer this way. Of course you can't always use it, but if you can, please do.

Answer (score 2):

After you call `l.remove`, the current element (`l.get(i)`) ends up being the next element (`"2"`).
However, after calling `remove`, you continue the loop and end up skipping the element.

To fix this, you can add `i--` inside the `if` so that the new current element gets processed by the next iteration (after `i++`)

Answer (score 1):

SLaks is correct as to what the problem is might i suggest syntax more like this.

```
int i=0;
while(i < l.size())
{
  if(l.get(i).equals("1"))
    l.remove(l.get(i));
  else
  {
    System.out.println(l.get(i++));
  }
}
```

Comment: ok.. An iterator did the job for me.. But ya. crappy mistake.. Thanks again guys :)

Answer (score -1):

If you take the else out it will give you the desired functionality.

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("1");
l.add("2");
l.add("3");
l.add("4");

for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {

    if(l.get(i).equals("1"))
        l.remove(l.get(i));

    System.out.println(l.get(i));
}
```